# How to filter dynamic HTML table using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am appending rows to the table whenever a event is occurring.But when I am trying to filter the table, I am only able to filter the static data in the table. How can I also filter the appended rows. Please help me with this.

//Filter rows

```
var $rows = $('#table tr');
$('#search').keyup(function() {

    var val = '^(?=.*\\b' + $.trim($(this).val()).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$',
        reg = RegExp(val, 'i'),
        text;

    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
        return !reg.test(text);
    }).hide();
});
```

Comment: Your `rows` var doesn't get updated with new rows. When you place the var declaration inside your method it will probably work.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `rows` is initialised with the rows in the DOM at the moment you tell jQuery to get those elements. No matter how many rows you add or remove, the `rows` variable will always have the same set of element. The quickest solution is to move your variable declaration inside the `keyup` handler like this:

```
$('#search').keyup(function() {
  var $rows = $('#table tr');
  var val = '^(?=.*\\b' + $.trim($(this).val()).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$',
    reg = RegExp(val, 'i'),
    text;

  $rows.show().filter(function() {
    text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
    return !reg.test(text);
  }).hide();
});
```

Another solution would the use `getElementsByTagName`, this returns a live HTMLCollection. In other words, changes in the DOM are reflected in your variable as they occur. The snippet below will log the number of rows in the table without re-querying the DOM.

```js
const
  tableTwo = document.getElementById('table2'),
  // Get a live HTMLCollection with the rows in table 2.
  tableTwoRows = tableTwo.getElementsByTagName('tr');
  
// Log the number of rows in table 2.
console.log(`Number of rows in table 2 before insert: ${tableTwoRows.length}`);

const
  cell = document.createElement('td'),
  row = document.createElement('tr'),
  body = tableTwo.querySelector('tbody');
  
// Create a third row to add to the table.
cell.textContent = 'table 2, row 3';
row.appendChild(cell);
body.appendChild(row);

// Log the number of rows in table 2, this should report a number than the last
// log eventhough we didn't update the content of the tableTwoRows variable manually.
console.log(`Number of rows in table 2 after insert: ${tableTwoRows.length}`);
```

```html
<table id="table1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>  
      <td>table 1, row 1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<table id="table2">
  <tbody>
    <tr>  
      <td>table 2, row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>table 2, row 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```